# Importing data from excel attachment on connect

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, import-from-excel

When importing data from the excel attachments on connect, the column headings appear as column data and it makes it difficult to work with the data. This is the what it comes out as. WebHits and Revenue should be the column headings

How do i make WebHits and Revenue the headings

I tried importing the data manually and by using a code that omits the NA values but it still doesn’t work

Comment: Can you please share some code showing how you're importing the file? Many functions for importing files have an argument that will allow you to set the first row as column names.

Comment: @Lindo George, your title is the opposite of what you describe in the question. Are you imprting TO Excel or FROM Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Using `readxl::read_excel`, you can tell how many lines to skip. (And then, if necessary, set your column names as you like.)